# Change directory in terminal - Access Denied

Tags: python, directory, pycharm, permission-denied, access-denied

I am working through a Udemy course. I am a Python beginner.

I am trying to change the directory in the Python terminal (in both Python 3.8 and PyCharm, same result). My current directory is `C:\Users\*username*\PycharmProjects\Woops\venv\Python For Beginners` and when I try to change directory using the following command:
`cd C:\Users\*username*\PycharmProjects\Woops\venv\Python For Beginners>python myparser.py`

I receive the message:

> "Access is denied."

I've gone into every folder and sub folder containing this item, and clicked on properties,  general and security and ensured that I have full permission. I've done the same for Python and PyCharm. I've gone into advanced security settings and the auditing and effective access headers and made sure my username has full access.

Finally, I've even opened PyCharm as an Administrator, and no matter what, when I enter the command:
`cd C:\Users\*username*\PycharmProjects\Woops\venv\Python For Beginners>python myparser.py`
it returns "Access is denied."

Anyone have an idea what is happening here, and how to execute the `cd` command?

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem is that you can't change the directory into a python file you can only change directories to a folder like for example

**Example**: cd C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Woops\venv\Python For Beginners

**To run the code write python3 or python myparser.py**